# OpenVPN client won't autostart ubuntu 18.04 proxmox LXC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to get OpenVPN to autostart a connection to the server but it does not seem to work.

I get the following output in /var/log/syslog

```
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.10.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=02:64:dc:2e:f3:8e
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: Note: Cannot set tx queue length on tun0: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
May 27 14:13:54 live networkd-dispatcher[145]: WARNING:Unknown index 2 seen, reloading interface list
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: openvpn_execve: unable to fork: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
May 27 14:13:54 live ovpn-client1[1231]: Exiting due to fatal error
May 27 14:13:54 live systemd[1]: openvpn@client1.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 27 14:13:54 live systemd[1]: openvpn@client1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

i have changed /etc/default/openvpn to have AUTOSTART="all" in the config file.

If i start openvpn as root with the following command, everything works perfectly.

```
root@live:~# openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/client1.conf
.....
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.10.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eth0 HWADDR=02:64:dc:2e:f3:8e
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 Note: Cannot set tx queue length on tun0: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.8.0.50 peer 255.255.255.255
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1570 10.8.0.50 255.255.255.255 init
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 255.255.255.255
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 GID set to nogroup
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 UID set to nobody
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Mon May 27 14:15:56 2019 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

I thought OpenVPN run as a root user by default, why does it not autostart via a service but will work fine when manually started?

I'm running the client in an ubnutu 18.04 server LXC container on a proxmox host.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be for several reasons: the first One a different configuration to run OpenVPN, the second One could it be due different networking configuration due string: 
Note: cannot set tx queue length on tun:0 operation not permitted (errno=1) 
The third reason could it be due troubles at the time to run OpenVPN with the browser, for that reason every time to used it no matter if auto start configuration done or not has to be manually configured.
The following file can help: 
https://www.ivpn.net/knowledgebase/226/Linux---Autostart-OpenVPN-in-systemd-Ubuntu.html